# ionisation isomers

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, isomers

[image]

With ionisation isomers, how do you know which ligand (out of $\ce{Br}$ and $\ce{NH3}$ for example) exchanges with the compound outside the bracket?

Comment: Well, as net charge is always the same, you are free to exchange any. I do remember water being involved in Cobalt chloride complexes, with change in lattice water. The same must apply for ammonia, too.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Do you mean how to make the difference between the 2 compounds if you have them in 2 different jars? Or do you mean how to study that exchange in a solution?